# How to display Picker.Item label with Dynamic values in array in react native

Tags: arrays, react-native, dropdown, picker

how can I pick 'label' of 'Picker.Item' from an array.
i have my picker code as follows:

```
<View style={Styles.inputWrapper}>
<Picker
selectedValue={this.state.expiryYear}
style={Styles.expYear}
onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ expiryYear:
itemValue })}>

<Picker.Item label="select" value="0" />
<Picker.Item label="2018" value="2018" />
<Picker.Item label="2019" value="2019" />
<Picker.Item label="2020" value="2020" />
<Picker.Item label="2021" value="2021" />
.
.
.
<Picker.Item label="2030" value="2030" />
</Picker>
</View>
```

I have an array 'years[]' with values 2018,2019,...,2030

```
        var years = [];
        for (y = 2018; y <= 2030; y++) {
          years.push([y]);
        }
```

In dropdown list I want to show years

Answer (score 1):

> You need to add below code in between your `<Picker> CODE </Picker>`

```
    years.map((year) => {
        return (
            <Picker.Item label={year} value={year} />
        )
    })
```

years is an array and has value whatever you want to render.(i mean how many years)

Comment: you need to define array first like:,

`var years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014];`

Comment: var years = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014]; tried with this again app stopped working. seems that something wrong with  array data. @Hardik

Comment: now try with one single element like `var years = [2000];`

Comment: trying with var years = ["2018","2019","2020"]; will works.ie (data without quotes  causes error) but not with for loop push

Comment: i doesnt need hardcorded  data. need dynamic data. how it is possible?